# Getting whole array printed instead of subsets

Tags: c++, c++17, bit-manipulation

I have used i&(1<<j)!=0 so that i get 1 or 0 in if condition specifying true or false but I am getting whole array printed instead of subsets. Though I get the correct result(subsets for given array) on using i&(1<<j).

```
void subsets(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<(1<<n);i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(i&(1<<j)!=0)
            {
                cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[3]={1,2,3};
    subsets(arr,3);
}
```

Comment: Review this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code failed to compile when building with `clang++` and `-Werror` flag, we will get this error:

```
operator_precendence.cpp:8:13: error: & has lower precedence than !=; != will be evaluated first [-Werror,-Wparentheses]
      if (i & (1 << j) != 0) {
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
operator_precendence.cpp:8:13: note: place parentheses around the '!=' expression to silence this warning
      if (i & (1 << j) != 0) {
            ^
              (            )
operator_precendence.cpp:8:13: note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it first
      if (i & (1 << j) != 0) {
            ^
          (           )
```

So it's clear that `!=` has been evaluated first, then the condition check always gets `true`. To fix it, we only need to add a parentheses (The compiler already give us the hints):

`if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0)` or simply use `if (i & (1 << j))`